# Real zeros of complex function

Tags: equation-solving, complex

I must find the zeros of a complex function $\xi$ that depends upon two real variables $B$ and $k$. The function is obtained by evaluating the determinant of the identity matrix of dimension $2n$ minus the product of two matrices $T$ and $S$ obtained by some procedure that is not important for the problem. In the case of $n=1$, it is possible to express the function $\xi$ analytically and in almost compact form. Specifically, we have

```
ξ[k_, B_] := (1/((Sqrt[2] - 2 I k)^8)) 32 E^(4 I k) (3 + 
    32 I Sqrt[2] k^7 (E^(-4 I k) - Cos[B]) + 
    16 I Sqrt[2] k^5 (2 + 3 E^(-2 I k) + E^(2 I k) - 7 E^(-4 I k) + Cos[B]) - 
    4 Cos[2 k] + Cos[4 k] + 16 k^8 (-Cos[B] + Cos[4 k]) + 
    32 Sqrt[2] E^(-I k) k Sin[k]^3 + 
    8 Sqrt[2] k^3 (I + 7 I E^(-4 I k) - 8 I Cos[2 k] - 12 Sin[2 k]) + 
    16 k^2 Sin[k]^2 (-1 + 6 Cos[2 k] - 8 I Sin[2 k]) + 
    16 k^6 (1 + 3 Cos[B] + 2 Cos[2 k] - 6 Cos[4 k] + 8 I Sin[4 k]) - 
    4 k^4 (9 + Cos[B] + 28 Cos[2 k] - 38 Cos[4 k] - 32 I Sin[2 k] + 32 I Sin[4 k]))
```

Fixing one of the two variables, either $B$ or $k$, I have searched for simultaneous solutions of the real and imaginary part of $\xi$ using `FindRoot`. However, this procedure fails when the determinant function has a zero derivative. This is because of Newton's method for finding the zeros used by default in `FindRoot`. Here I have not understood how to use a more efficient method in `FindRoot` for a two-dimensional search.

I am now using a different strategy based on finding the minima of the `Abs[ξ]`. This strategy has fewer problems when the $\xi$ has zero derivatives locally.

My concern is that when the variable $n$ increases, the complexity of $\xi$ increases as well.

I am looking for suggestions or alternative to tackle this problem.

Answer (score 5):

Your function $\xi(k,B)$ does not depend on $B$ directly but only on $\cos(B)$, in a simple way. You can solve $\xi=0$ for $\cos(B)$ and thus find $\cos(B)$ as a function of $k$.

```
ξ[k_, B_] = (1/((Sqrt[2] - 2 I k)^8))32 E^(4 I k) (3 + 32 I Sqrt[2] k^7 (E^(-4 I k) - Cos[B]) + 16 I Sqrt[2] k^5 (2 + 3 E^(-2 I k) + E^(2 I k) - 7 E^(-4 I k) + Cos[B]) -    4 Cos[2 k] + Cos[4 k] + 16 k^8 (-Cos[B] + Cos[4 k]) +    32 Sqrt[2] E^(-I k) k Sin[k]^3 +    8 Sqrt[2] k^3 (I + 7 I E^(-4 I k) - 8 I Cos[2 k] - 12 Sin[2 k]) +    16 k^2 Sin[k]^2 (-1 + 6 Cos[2 k] - 8 I Sin[2 k]) +    16 k^6 (1 + 3 Cos[B] + 2 Cos[2 k] - 6 Cos[4 k] + 8 I Sin[4 k]) -    4 k^4 (9 + Cos[B] + 28 Cos[2 k] - 38 Cos[4 k] - 32 I Sin[2 k] + 32 I Sin[4 k]));

cosB[k_] = SolveValues[ξ[k, B] == 0, Cos[B]] // First // ComplexExpand // FullSimplify
(*    (3 + 4 k^2 + (1 + 4 k^2 (-3 + k^2)) Cos[4 k] + 8 Sqrt[2] k Sin[2 k] + 4 (-1 + 2 k^2) (Cos[2 k] + Sqrt[2] k Sin[4 k]))/(4 k^4)    *)


Plot[cosB[k], {k, -3, 3}]
```

[image]

There are infinitely many solutions for $B$ that give this value of $\cos(B)$, of course. One of these branches is

```
Plot[ArcCos[cosB[k]], {k, -10, 10}]
```

[image]

Plotting a few more branches for a more complete picture:

```
Plot[Evaluate[
  Join @@ Table[{2π*n + ArcCos[cosB[k]], 
                 2π*n - ArcCos[cosB[k]]},
                {n, -3, 3}]], {k, -10, 10},
                AxesLabel -> {k, B}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
xsi[k_, B_] := (1/((Sqrt[2] - 2 I k)^8)) 32 E^(4 I k) (3 + 
    32 I Sqrt[2] k^7 (E^(-4 I k) - Cos[B]) + 
    16 I Sqrt[
      2] k^5 (2 + 3 E^(-2 I k) + E^(2 I k) - 7 E^(-4 I k) + Cos[B]) - 
    4 Cos[2 k] + Cos[4 k] + 16 k^8 (-Cos[B] + Cos[4 k]) + 
    32 Sqrt[2] E^(-I k) k Sin[k]^3 + 
    8 Sqrt[2] k^3 (I + 7 I E^(-4 I k) - 8 I Cos[2 k] - 12 Sin[2 k]) + 
    16 k^2 Sin[k]^2 (-1 + 6 Cos[2 k] - 8 I Sin[2 k]) + 
    16 k^6 (1 + 3 Cos[B] + 2 Cos[2 k] - 6 Cos[4 k] + 8 I Sin[4 k]) - 
    4 k^4 (9 + Cos[B] + 28 Cos[2 k] - 38 Cos[4 k] - 32 I Sin[2 k] + 
       32 I Sin[4 k]))

ContourPlot[{Re[xsi[k, B]] == 0, Im[xsi[k, B]] == 0}, {k, 0, 5}, {B,0 , 5 }, ContourStyle -> {Red, {Dashed, Black}},MaxRecursion -> 4(*,PlotPoints\[Rule]100*)]
```

[image]

At the intersections of blue(realpart==0) and red(imaginary part==0) function `xsi ==0`

`NSolve` evaluates the solution

```
sol=NSolve[{Re[xsi[k, B]] == 0, Im[xsi[k, B]] == 0, 0 < k <= 5, 
0 < B <= 5}, {k, B} ]
ListPlot[{k, B} /. sol , Joined -> ! True]
```

[image]